# Multiple Vlookup, Return all Date Matches in a Single Cell Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I'm wondering if there's a way to return all vlookup matches in a single cell with a comma as a delimiter,

For example say i have the following data

A       B
1  Jane   1/2/223

2  Adam   4/6/23

3  Adam   6/20/23

4  John   2/2/23

Is there are way to use a lookup to give all matches for Adam in a single cell as follows:

4/6/23,6/20/23

Hope this is clear.

Thanks!